# Showing a view controller modally in monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

In my Monotouch based iOS project , i have 2 view controllers .On first ViewController i have created a button by xib.
Now on selection of this button i want to display the second view controller but it is not happening and it causes the application to crash.

So in my design.cs file this is the way the button is created

```
[Outlet]
MonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton firstButton { get; set; }

[Action ("clickMe:")]
partial void clickMe (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender);
```

This is in my button action method in .cs file,  which is causing the crash.

```
partial void clickMe (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender)

{

SecondViewController secondViewControllerObject=new SecondViewController();

this.PresentViewController(secondViewControllerObject, true, null);

}
```

Error Description :-

Got a SIGABRT while executing native code.

Terminating runtime due to unhandled exception

```
Unhandled Exception:
0   TestingFirstProject                 0x0008ebce mono_handle_exception_internal_first_pass + 2190
1   TestingFirstProject                 0x00090612 mono_handle_exception_internal + 1602
2   TestingFirstProject                 0x0009115f mono_handle_exception + 47
3   TestingFirstProject                 0x000d42b2 mono_x86_throw_exception + 306
4   ???                                 0x0b496f8f 0x0 + 189362063
5   TestingFirstProject                 0x00215f38 monotouch_exception_handler + 136
6   CoreFoundation                      0x013ca318 __handleUncaughtException + 728
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0401d0b9 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 86
8   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0435ea65 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 13
9   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0435eacd __cxa_bad_typeid + 0
10  libc++abi.dylib                     0x0435fbc2 _ZL23__gxx_exception_cleanup19_Unwind_Reason_CodeP17_Unwind_Exception + 0
11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0401cf89 _ZL26_objc_exception_destructorPv + 0
12  CoreFoundation                      0x013c9fb1 -[NSException raise] + 17
13  Foundation                          0x01a08711 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
14  Foundation                          0x01989ec8 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 140
15  Foundation                          0x019899b7 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
16  Foundation                          0x019b4428 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
17  UIKit                               0x029410cc -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
18  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04030663 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
19  CoreFoundation                      0x0133c45a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
20  UIKit                               0x0293fbcf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1327
21  UIKit                               0x02804e37 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
22  UIKit                               0x02805418 -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
23  UIKit                               0x02805648 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 73
24  UIKit                               0x02805882 -[UIViewController view] + 33
25  UIKit                               0x02811235 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
26  UIKit                               0x02a103d2 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1933
27  UIKit                               0x0280e4f3 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4521
28  UIKit                               0x0280e777 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 112
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_bool_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,bool,intptr) <IL 0x00016, 0x00044>
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.PresentViewController (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController,bool,MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction) [0x0006f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:659
at TestingFirstProject.TestingFirstProjectViewController.clickMe (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject) [0x00006] in /Users/rock/Desktop/Sample Project/TestingFirstProject/TestingFirstProject/TestingFirstProjectViewController.cs:41
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0004b, 0x0007d>
33  TestingFirstProject                 0x00009922 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
34  TestingFirstProject                 0x0016c4ae mono_runtime_invoke + 126
35  TestingFirstProject                 0x0020f086 monotouch_trampoline + 3686
36  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04030705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
37  UIKit                               0x02727920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
38  UIKit                               0x027278b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
39  UIKit                               0x027e8671 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
40  UIKit                               0x027e8bcf -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
41  UIKit                               0x027e7d38 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
42  UIKit                               0x0275733f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
43  UIKit                               0x02757552 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
44  UIKit                               0x027353aa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
45  UIKit                               0x02726cf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
46  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0fdf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
47  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0fad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
48  CoreFoundation                      0x012b6bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
49  CoreFoundation                      0x012b6962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
50  CoreFoundation                      0x012e7bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
51  CoreFoundation                      0x012e6f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
52  CoreFoundation                      0x012e6e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
53  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0e7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
54  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0e668 GSEventRun + 104
55  UIKit                               0x0272465c UIApplicationMain + 1211
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00056, 0x000a4>
at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
at TestingFirstProject.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/rock/Desktop/Sample Project/TestingFirstProject/TestingFirstProject/Main.cs:17
at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00049, 0x00077>
60  TestingFirstProject                 0x00009922 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
61  TestingFirstProject                 0x0016c4ae mono_runtime_invoke + 126
62  TestingFirstProject                 0x001706a4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
63  TestingFirstProject                 0x00175a95 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
64  TestingFirstProject                 0x00066e05 mono_jit_exec + 149
65  TestingFirstProject                 0x0020433d main + 2013
66  TestingFirstProject                 0x00002955 start + 53

[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<SecondViewController 0x12a36ca0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key butnSubmit.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_bool_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,bool,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.PresentViewController (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController viewControllerToPresent, Boolean animated, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction completionHandler) [0x0006f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:659 
  at TestingFirstProject.TestingFirstProjectViewController.clickMe (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject sender) [0x00006] in /Users/rock/Desktop/Sample Project/TestingFirstProject/TestingFirstProject/TestingFirstProjectViewController.cs:41 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38 
  at TestingFirstProject.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/rock/Desktop/Sample Project/TestingFirstProject/TestingFirstProject/Main.cs:17 
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    0   TestingFirstProject                 0x0009148c mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
    1   TestingFirstProject                 0x000d769d sigabrt_signal_handler + 109
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x9a4c386b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   libsystem_sim_c.dylib               0x041e057b abort + 140
    5   TestingFirstProject                 0x001ea3fd monoeg_g_logv + 157
    6   TestingFirstProject                 0x001ea42b monoeg_assertion_message + 43
    7   TestingFirstProject                 0x00215e5f monotouch_unhandled_exception_handler + 159
    8   TestingFirstProject                 0x0008cefc mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 140
    9   TestingFirstProject                 0x0009100a mono_handle_exception_internal + 4154
    10  TestingFirstProject                 0x0009115f mono_handle_exception + 47
    11  TestingFirstProject                 0x000d42b2 mono_x86_throw_exception + 306
    12  ???                                 0x0b496f8f 0x0 + 189362063
    13  TestingFirstProject                 0x00215f38 monotouch_exception_handler + 136
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x013ca318 __handleUncaughtException + 728
    15  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0401d0b9 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 86
    16  libc++abi.dylib                     0x0435ea65 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 13
    17  libc++abi.dylib                     0x0435eacd __cxa_bad_typeid + 0
    18  libc++abi.dylib                     0x0435fbc2 _ZL23__gxx_exception_cleanup19_Unwind_Reason_CodeP17_Unwind_Exception + 0
    19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0401cf89 _ZL26_objc_exception_destructorPv + 0
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x013c9fb1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    21  Foundation                          0x01a08711 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    22  Foundation                          0x01989ec8 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 140
    23  Foundation                          0x019899b7 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    24  Foundation                          0x019b4428 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    25  UIKit                               0x029410cc -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    26  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04030663 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0133c45a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    28  UIKit                               0x0293fbcf -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1327
    29  UIKit                               0x02804e37 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 280
    30  UIKit                               0x02805418 -[UIViewController loadView] + 302
    31  UIKit                               0x02805648 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 73
    32  UIKit                               0x02805882 -[UIViewController view] + 33
    33  UIKit                               0x02811235 -[UIViewController shouldAutorotate] + 36
    34  UIKit                               0x02a103d2 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1933
    35  UIKit                               0x0280e4f3 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4521
    36  UIKit                               0x0280e777 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 112
    37  ???                                 0x129333bc 0x0 + 311636924
    38  ???                                 0x12933118 0x0 + 311636248
    39  ???                                 0x12932ff5 0x0 + 311635957
    40  ???                                 0x12931ff5 0x0 + 311631861
    41  TestingFirstProject                 0x00009922 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
    42  TestingFirstProject                 0x0016c4ae mono_runtime_invoke + 126
    43  TestingFirstProject                 0x0020f086 monotouch_trampoline + 3686
    44  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x04030705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    45  UIKit                               0x02727920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    46  UIKit                               0x027278b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    47  UIKit                               0x027e8671 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    48  UIKit                               0x027e8bcf -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
    49  UIKit                               0x027e7d38 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
    50  UIKit                               0x0275733f -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
    51  UIKit                               0x02757552 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    52  UIKit                               0x027353aa -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
    53  UIKit                               0x02726cf8 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
    54  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0fdf9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
    55  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0fad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    56  CoreFoundation                      0x012b6bf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    57  CoreFoundation                      0x012b6962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    58  CoreFoundation                      0x012e7bb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
    59  CoreFoundation                      0x012e6f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
    60  CoreFoundation                      0x012e6e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    61  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0e7e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
    62  GraphicsServices                    0x04d0e668 GSEventRun + 104
    63  UIKit                               0x0272465c UIApplicationMain + 1211
    64  ???                                 0x0e9ccd74 0x0 + 245157236
    65  ???                                 0x0e9cb3e8 0x0 + 245150696
    66  ???                                 0x0e9cabe8 0x0 + 245148648
    67  ???                                 0x0e9cac77 0x0 + 245148791
    68  TestingFirstProject                 0x00009922 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
    69  TestingFirstProject                 0x0016c4ae mono_runtime_invoke + 126
    70  TestingFirstProject                 0x001706a4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
    71  TestingFirstProject                 0x00175a95 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
    72  TestingFirstProject                 0x00066e05 mono_jit_exec + 149
    73  TestingFirstProject                 0x0020433d main + 2013
    74  TestingFirstProject                 0x00002955 start + 53

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: Could you share the code for the second controller, I wondering if there is something about it that needs looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key bit of information in your exception is:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key butnSubmit

Which means that you have a property on your C# class which doesn't have a corresponding outlet in the .xib (interface builder) file.

Re-check/recreate your outlets, and see if that solves the problem.